# redsocks redirect port 443 -> Tor: Missing mapping for virtual address

Tags: mac, ssl

I'm trying to redirect some port 443 connections through tor using redsocks. But when redsocks accesses tor, the client connections get dropped, and tor gives this warning:

```
[warn] Missing mapping for virtual address '[scrubbed]'. Refusing.
```

I'm using Tor 0.2.4.23 and redsocks/0.4 with Osx 10.9.

The redirection is done with pfctl in `pf.conf` like this:

```
rdr pass on $src inet proto tcp from any to any port 443 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8888
```

I don't have an idea what the issue is here. Plz, someone help! :)

Answer (score 1):

For that to work, you need a `SocksPort` line in Tor's configuration file, `torrc`. Using `OS X`, that's probably `~/.tor/torrc` or `/Library/Tor/torrc`. You need to add this line:

```
SocksPort 8888
```